# selecting operating system to serve rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, operating-system

Vps hosting provides choice of operating system:

- Cent OS 5
- Debian 4.0
- Fedora 10
- Gentoo
- Opensuse 10
- Ubuntu 8.10
- Ubuntu 8.04
- Ubuntu 9.04

Which pros and cons for running rails app, software installing, overall feel, etc. do they have, or maybe there are others which are much better to serve rails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all industrial strength unix OSes and will all run RoR on with Apache extremely well.

The main difference is ease of admin and ease of mainteneance. Cent OS is designed for remote server installations and has lots of nice management features, Ubuntu is probably the eaiest to maintain -- it just sort of happens.

I would go for Ubuntu 8.0 over Ubuntu 9.0 as the older OS is has proven to be extremely stable. (In fact for server apps stick with the Ubuntu "long term support" releases unless you like applying patches!).

Comment: Did i got it right, you mean Ubuntu 8.04?
Using google I found people telling that Cent OS is more for server and Ubuntu is more for desktop, is it true?

Comment: Its really an ease of management vs. ease of software maintainance thing. If you are actually developing on the server or you have lots of complex libraries I would go for Ubuntu, otherwise, the ease of deployment and system management of CentOS wins.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu LTS releases have a good track record, and many other rails users use ubuntu so most blog posts etc will be easy to follow.

But since you are going to be digging around in there often, overall I would recommend you use whichever you have the most experience with.

Comment: As I understand, 8.04 is LTS?

Answer (score 1):

Companies like Engine Yard have made a whole business out of using Gentoo. I too have used Gentoo as the Operating System for over 5 apps thus far.  I won't change either.

Emerge is the package manager, and the community keeps you up to date with security updates pretty dang quick too.

When you compile (fancy word for install, if you don't know) your packages, they also include things like a user, and sane defaults.  So installing postgres is as simple as `emerge install postgresql` and you are good (enough) to start, with less config then another OS.

[My go to gist for setting up a server](https://gist.github.com/ed8fd66f1547d94b6be2)